# Omitting ΔVbe in emitter follower KVL equations

Tags: transistors, bjt, emitter-follower

In the forward active region, if we draw an emitter follower voltage variations as follows:

[image]

It seems by using KVL we can say that:

> ΔVin = ΔVbe + ΔVe

Now in many texts they omit ΔVbe and equate ΔVe to ΔVin.

Is ΔVbe caused by the dynamic resistance of the base emitter junction?

If so, how small should that be comparing to the emitter resistor(Re) to be able to omit ΔVbe? Can you give some practical values?

Comment: Have you calculated (or simulated) how much \$\Delta V_{be}\$ is for your circuit, given a reasonable output load?

Comment: I haven't done with a particlualr value, but I know that ΔVbe creates the Ic & Ie according to the Ebers Moll model. If the Re were zero ΔVbe would become equal to the ΔVin. But when Re increases to some value the ΔVbe is neglected. I was wondering whether it is due to the base emitter junction dynamic resistance being too small comparing to Re.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an approximation to the base emitter junction you can use a forward biased diode to predict what ΔVbe might be. For instance, a 1N4148 diode has the following characteristic: -

[image]

- If you have a quiescent base current of around 100 uA DC there would be approximately 500 mV DC dropped across the diode.
- If your input signal caused that base current to alter +/- 50 uA you can see that ΔVbe would be around +/- 30 mV.
- This gives rise (via a \$\beta\$ value of say 100) to an emitter current change of +/- 5 mA on a standing emitter current of 10 mA.
- If your emitter resistor is (say) 1000 ohms, that's a DC output voltage of 10 volts with a superimposed AC voltage (due to your input signal) of 10 volt p-p.

So the ΔVbe of 60 mVp-p, when compared to 10 Vp-p is 0.6% and not that big of a deal to ignore.